# Where should I ask my question about video animation (sort of)?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

**Background**

I want to create a intro video/video bumper for my YouTube channel and videos.

I found [this site](https://www.renderforest.com) and I liked [this intro video](https://www.renderforest.com/template/rubiks-cube-logo-reveal), but the site gives a watermark with a free trial and I don't have the funds to buy a subscription.

So I want to ask a question if it's possible to create this template manually.

Also I want ask about how to make any type of short animation like an image rotating and then other images appearing in it with a circular entry style.

**Question**

Which Stack Exchange site will be suitable for my question? *[Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com/tour)* or *[Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour)*?

I think *Blender*, but my question is not fixed to particularly [Blender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blender_%28software%29)!

Comment: So I found the softwares- Adobe after effects and Blender. Stack site that is adequate is graphic design (in my opinion) it has Adobe After-Effects tag too. So now what should I do with this post?

Comment: You should join that site and migrate your question over there with you. You should also avoid posting answers as comments.